# Node - restler - ECONNRESET

Tags: node.js, rest, https

I know that this topic has many threads.
But i cant find any solutions to the problem.

Using Node(0.10.*) with "restler" as a REST module.

The rest API use **HTTPS**

One api service work 100% but another works 1/5 rest calls and i get ECONNRESET. I know what the error stand for.

But, when i use Postman to do the rest call they work 100% :/

Exampel code:

```
rest.get(config.endPoint + "/focus/api?method=findsc&cid=" + collectionId + "&fid=" + textId + "&max=" + limit + "&apikey=" + config.apiKey + "&format=json").on('complete', function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                callback(true, data.data.items);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I skipt then plugin and used `var https = require('https');` instead but i did have to add this to make it work.

```
https.globalAgent.options.secureProtocol = 'SSLv3_method';
```